# How can I specify a 'formula' while building widgets: flutter

Tags: flutter

I have something like this at multiple places (ignore the actual example). When I make changes to these formulae, I need to make the changes in multiple files.

```
SizedBox(
        width: parentPortHidden ? 0.01 : DevicePreferences.getViewPortWidth(context, Constants.defaultDeviceWidth) - 0.01,
        height: DevicePreferences.getDeviceHeight(context, Constants.getActualDeviceHeight) -
            DevicePreferences.getDeviceHeight(context, Constants.appBarRelativeHeight, Constants.appBarMinAbsHeight),
        child: CustomScrollView(
```

the values for width and height are computed with the same formula (and these are not constants)

Perhaps this question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458971/define-equivalent-in-dart-flutter) on the equivalent of #define in Flutter, but I am not sure if there is another solution, since there is none for #define...

If there is no code solution, what will be the best 'system' to use to ensure that changes are made everywhere these formulae need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple function, that will implement your formula, like this:

```
double f(bool parentPortHidden, double ViewPortWidth)
{
  return parentPortHidden ? 0.01 : ViewPortWidth - 0.01;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SmirnuX - that does not solve my requirement. Let me explain:
**double f(bool parentPortHidden, double ViewPortWidth)**
supposes that I just have two parameters. What if the formula changes and has more/less parameters, I'd still need to change the calling function everywhere, and be not much better off.

Comment: You can create class, that will be responsible for computing your formula. For example, it can contain functions like `static double GetW()`, that will return value depending of parameters, passed to class earlier. With that solution you'll have to pass parameters to class once, and later just call `class_name.GetW()`. If you would want to add or remove parameters, you'll have to change only fragment of code, where you pass parameters to class.